# Array values not updated properly

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue where I want to use an existing array and update one of it's properties using a for loop. I expect the outer id and the id inside the array to match, so for example: a & a, b & b, c & c. However when I print out my final array, all of the inner ids are set to c.

I don't understand why this happens?

edit: added expected output

**My Code**

```
  const accounts = [{ 
      "id": 1,
      "currency": "USD"
  }];

  const alphaId = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  
  let finalArr = []; 

  for (index in alphaId) {
  
    let newAccount = {};
    newAccount.id = alphaId[index];
  
    newAccount.accounts = accounts;
    newAccount.accounts.forEach(acc => {
      acc.id = alphaId[index];
    });

    finalArr.push(newAccount);
  }
```

**Print Out**

```
[
  {
    "id": "a",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "id": "c",
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "b",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "id": "c",
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "c",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "id": "c",
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
  {
    "id": "a",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "id": "a",
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "b",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "id": "b",
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "c",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "id": "c",
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: added the expected output, sorry @kennarddh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
newAccount.accounts = accounts;
```

That just makes the property `accounts` on the new object refer to the **same array** as `accounts`, it doesn't copy the array. So all your code is working on the same array, and on the same object within that array.

I suspect you meant to copy both the array and the objects in it. We can do that with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), having it return new objects.

```
newAccount.accounts = accounts.map((account) => ({...account}));
```

That uses `map`, [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) *(it's not an operator)*, and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It's using the concise form of an arrow function (no `{` after the arrow) where the body is just an expression. Since what we're returning is an object literal, which starts with `{`, we have to wrap the entire body in `()` so the parser realizes we're using the concise form. Here's what it would look like if we used the "verbose" form:

```
newAccount.accounts = accounts.map((account) => {
    return {...account};
});
```

Here's the minimal updated version, but keep reading:

```js
const accounts = [
    {
        id: 1,
        currency: "USD",
    },
];

const alphaId = ["a", "b", "c"];

let finalArr = [];

for (index in alphaId) {
    let newAccount = {};
    newAccount.id = alphaId[index];

    newAccount.accounts = accounts.map((account) => ({...account}));
    newAccount.accounts.forEach((acc) => {
        acc.id = alphaId[index];
    });

    finalArr.push(newAccount);
}

console.log(finalArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

That loops through `accounts` twice: once to make the copy, and then again to assign the `id`. We can do it just once by assigning the `id` while making the copy, using `map`:

```
newAccount.accounts = accounts.map((account) => ({...account, id: alphaId[index]}));
```

```js
const accounts = [
    {
        id: 1,
        currency: "USD",
    },
];

const alphaId = ["a", "b", "c"];

let finalArr = [];

for (index in alphaId) {
    let newAccount = {};
    newAccount.id = alphaId[index];

    newAccount.accounts = accounts.map((account) => ({...account, id: alphaId[index]}));

    finalArr.push(newAccount);
}

console.log(finalArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Some other notes:

1. `for-in` isn't the correct way to loop through an array (usually), see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/157247) for full details of your various options.
2. Since `finalArr` is a mapping of `alphaId`'s ID values to objects, we can use `map` instead of the loop, handling creating the new accounts within the `map`:

Example:

```
const finalArr = alphaId.map((id) => ({
    id,
    accounts: accounts.map((account) => ({...account, id})),
}));
```

```js
const accounts = [
    {
        id: 1,
        currency: "USD",
    },
];

const alphaId = ["a", "b", "c"];

const finalArr = alphaId.map((id) => ({
    id,
    accounts: accounts.map((account) => ({...account, id})),
}));

console.log(finalArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much @T.J. Crowder! This is a really great in-depth answer and helps to answer lots of my questions I had. Your explanations are very easy to understand. I will do more reading on the links you provided on the spread syntax and take a look at that link to your for-in explanation as well. I have much to learn. I really appreciate it.